# How to add Future builder along with card constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to add the code below to my existing card constructor but I am unable to do so

```
child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          child: FutureBuilder<Uri>(
              future: createDynamicLink(), //return link
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  Uri? uri = snapshot.data;
                  return FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    onPressed: () => FlutterShare.share(title: 'Example share',
                        text: 'Example share text',
                        linkUrl: uri.toString(),
                        chooserTitle: 'Example Chooser Title'),
                    child: Text('Share'),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ),
```

And this is the card widget with which I want to add the future function

```
child: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120.0),
    child: GridView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      children: events.map((title){
        return Scaffold(body:

       Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image:DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/bg.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover),),
            return GestureDetector(
              child: Card(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),   
              ),
              onDoubleTap: () {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "msg");
              },
              
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
```

[image]

I want to be able to use the future function along with the flutterShare functionality when I click on one of the grid card

The event list used above:

```
List<String> events = [
    "Emergency SMS",
    "Call",
    "Navigation"
  ];
```

Truly appreciate any help!

Comment: Is this the complete code? It looks like you're using `map()` in your code. Can you please share the full code?

Comment: Apologies. I have just updated the code.

Comment: If `createDynamicLink()` is returning a future, then you need to store the future in state. If you read the documentation for `FutureBuilder` it will explain that you _must not_ create the future in the build method https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html